# How to achieve camera culling in the blender?

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

I have a large scene and would like to have the objects in the camera's field of view rendered and the rest removed.
Has this feature not been developed yet?

Comment: Hello, are you using eevee or cycles ?

Comment: @Gorgious i use cycles.

Comment: If the answer below is to your liking, could you please mark it as the answer? If not, let us know what you'd like answered then.

Answer (score 7):

With Cycles, this answer is easy. The feature is there, but may not be stable. Go to your Render properties panel, down to Simplify subpanel (check its box) and find the Culling section.

[image: Render properties -> Simplify -> Culling]

From the manual:

- **Camera Cull** Automatically culls objects based on the camera frustum defined by the Margin.
- **Distance Cull** Automatically culls objects based on their distance from the active camera. This is set via the Distance property.

If you enable *both*, it's an and case: the object will only cull if it's outside camera view *and* beyond the distance property. Useful for keeping reflected objects in scene.

Hold on, you're not done yet: you have to go each object you want to be cull-able and set it to be so. Go to the Object properties panel, then the Visibility subpanel and check the appropriate box.

[image: Object panel -> Visibility -> Culling]

Tedious? Yes. And I say not stable because some of the source code contradicts (such as that lights are viable to be culled, but don't seem to be - feel free to correct me). But otherwise, it does what you want.

As for other renderers or the viewport - Eevee and viewport do their own culling, although they may have their own optimizations planned. The best universal way is to manually enable or disable object and collection visibility in the outliner.

Comment: Tedious? No. Select them all and alt+click the box.

Comment: True, alt-clicking works well. I forgot that I also made an add-on that puts all the settings in one place, as well as a list of all the objects with toggles for each one: https://github.com/semagnum/cy-culls